# Stopping Gunicorn running in a schroot session

Tags: gunicorn, supervisord, schroot

I'm running a Gunicorn server inside a schroot session via supervisor. My problem is that the service is not fully stopped when stopping it with "supervisorctl stop".

This is the script (simplified) controlling my server, it runs gunicorn in foreground:

```
# gunicorn.sh
schroot -c gunicorn -r -- bash -c "gunicorn --workers=1 myapp.wsgi:application"
```

This is my supervisor config to run this script:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/home/test/gunicorn.sh
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn.out.log
```

When I start the service via "supervisorctl start" , my process tree looks like this:

```
supervisord(7175)---gunicorn.sh(8061)---schroot(8067)---gunicorn(8068)---gunicorn(8073)---{gunicorn}(8078)
```

Now when I stop the service with "supervisorctl stop", The corresponding supervisor process and its direct child, gunicorn.sh, are terminated.
But the schroot process itself continues to live and is now a child of the init process:

```
schroot(8067)---gunicorn(8068)---gunicorn(8073)---{gunicorn}(8078)
```

This whole behavior seems to be related to both the way schroot and gunicorn work.

How can I let supervisor stop my schroot-hosted process correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to start gunicorn with exec:

```
# gunicorn.sh
exec schroot -c gunicorn -r -- bash -c "gunicorn --workers=1 myapp.wsgi:application"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the exact same problem today -- but the accepted solution did not work.  Same problem is referenced for example [here](http://supervisor-users.supervisord.narkive.com/QA9opRMN/supervisorctl-stop-does-not-stop-gunicorn-running-inside-a-schroot-session).

Running a program using a supervisor generally requires that anything you execute is done using exec() system call -- as it replaces the original process with itself, leaving the PID (which is important) for supervisor to manage (without detaching from a terminal, of course).

Starting a gunicorn in schroot session always produces two processes -- the schroot -- which is referenced by supervisor -- and the gunicorn master (workers are not important).

Invoking stop in supervisor just kills the schroot and makes the gunicorn master to migrate to init (PID=1) leaving it actually running.

Without the chroot, the easiest way is to just 'exec gunicorn /whatever/'.

Workaround I have found which seems to be ok is like that:

1. Start the schroot gunicorn process with pidproxy helper program (from supervisor distribution, /usr/bin/pidproxy)
2. Write the PID of the gunicorn process to file (usually by modifying your application startup)
3. Properly use exec whenever possible.

Ad 1. Use the pidproxy

```
[program:xxx]
command = pidproxy /path/to/pid/file /path/to/xxx
```

Ad 2. Use whatever means to write the pid to file.  I just used the following code snippet during my app startup:

```
pid_file = os.path.join(conf.data_dir, "eventaid.pid")
with open(pid_file, "w") as fout:
    fout.write(str(os.getpid()))
```

Ad 3. Use exec in your script /path/to/xxx

```
# activate venv
. $HOME/.virtualenvs/python3-xxx/bin/activate
# start within schroot
exec schroot -c jessie -- sh -c "exec gunicorn <whatever>"
```

Now sending the SIGTERM/SIGKILL/... from within the supervisor will actually send the SIGTERM/SIGKILL/... to the pidproxy that will forward the signal to gunicorn PID actually killing it.